# Python crashes running assemble_data.py for Flickr Style dataset

Tags: caffe

I'm trying to download the Flickr Style dataset using `assemble_data.py` provided in the examples folder. However, whenever I run this python crashes with error 'python quit unexpectedly'.

It seems to be related to multiprocessing and urllib. When I replace `pool.map` with a single threaded loop it works but is very slow. Also, if I run with multiprocessing but remove `urlretrieve` it seems to work too.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here... I resolved this by using urllib3 instead.

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(10)
def download_image(args_tuple):
    "For use with multiprocessing map. Returns filename on fail."
    url, filename = args_tuple
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            print url + ' -> ' + filename
            # Dont redirect.
            response = http.request('GET', url, redirect=False)
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.data)
        with open(filename) as f:
            assert hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest() != MISSING_IMAGE_SHA1
        test_read_image = io.imread(filename)
        return True
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise Exception()  # multiprocessing doesn't catch keyboard exceptions
    except:
        os.remove(filename)
        return False
```

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/sthomp/48d35095a414580c055b).

Comment: Thanks a lot, had the same problem and your solution worked perfectly!